# Video capture, one device to another via usb-c only

Tags: usb, video, streaming

I was capturing gameplay on one linux device via another. (for Twitch streaming). I had connected them thusly,

Gaming PC -> usb-c video output dongle -> HDMI cable -> usb-c capture dongle  -> Streaming PC

And I realized how silly this was. Why do I need to use to 2 dongles to convert to hdmi and back. Is here a solution to just connect 2 pc's via usb, and send the screen from one to capture on the other?

Comment: I think this is a hardware question and does not belong on this site.

Comment: Indeed ^^^ At first glance this has nothing to do with Linux. And it doesn't make sense regardless the OS to ask *your* undisclosed hardware works the way it does and/or if it can work in some other way. Your question is likely a better fit for Superuser but even there make sure to post the full hardware specifications and software involved.

Comment: I assumed a solution would be a software one. A combination of some drivers and commands. I already have a hardware solution, as I described in the question. I'm looking for a software way to drop all that unnecessary hardware and reduce that hardware to just a single usb-c cable.

Comment: Also, I'm connecting linux to linux.

Comment: I'm looking into this as well.  I have found mention of UVC and UAC, USB video class and USB audio class.  Something about libGUVC, the library for UVC gadgets that can enable sending video over USB in some compressed format as if the computer is a webcam.  This has apparently been done, but takes some work on the computer sending video to emulate the USB video device.